# Malicious company advertising with SO Careers

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I am currently being robocalled by a company that is advertising on SO Careers. I will typically receive two calls a day on weekdays, one before my alarm clock goes off in the morning, and one after lunch. If I answer one of these calls the auto dialer will hang up and schedule a human to call me within a short time period. Every time that I have talked to a human from this company they have informed me that they will "take me off the auto dialer list", however I am still receiving calls two weeks later. I have resorted to blocking the phone number of the auto dialer, even though my phone still notifies me every time they have attempted to call me.

I do not recall giving out my information to this company, and I have confirmed with SO that I have never had any contact with the company through SO. However, whenever using SO Careers I stumbled across one of their forty five advertised positions. I used the contact form on the website to reiterate this story in hopes of having the companies ability to advertise on SO Careers be impacted negatively. Instead the response that I received from SO was that since the abusive interactions that I have had with the company are not directed through SO, the only thing they offered to do was to direct my email to the company that is spamming me.

I would expect this from any other careers website, but I thought SO had enough integrity to do something in a situation like this to prevent this company from getting a hold of any other users personal data and harassing them as they have done to me. Am I getting an acceptable response to my complaints to SO? Personally I think it is in their best interests to try and protect the careers users from any malicious companies, their response makes it seem as though it is not their problem.

Comment: The fact that this company is robocalling you and the fact that this company is advertising on SO seem mutually exclusive, especially if you've already confirmed with SO that you have never contacted them before.

Comment: One thing you have to consider is SO's ability to validate claims of mis-behavior of a company outside of their system.  For example, a disgruntled ex-employee could go to SO fraudulently claiming that some company was engaging in bad hiring practices outside of SO's system in the hopes of getting SO to pull their careers access.

Comment: I can provide the phone logs and phone numbers that they were utilizing to robo call me, In addition the company was openly admitting that they were using auto dailers. If SO had the interest to pursue this, it wouldn't be difficult to find out the truth.

Comment: Yes @Makoto They are mutually exclusive, I am not trying to get SO to force the company to stop calling me. I am trying to get SO to not help the company do this to other people.

Comment: @HatterisMad So let's say that I gave you a bunch of phone numbers (and dates/times of calls received) that I claimed were from an auto-dialer that was spamming me.  How would you go about verifying that the phone number was in fact from that company, and it was in fact calling me?

Comment: Well, in my exact instance. I would be able to provide phone records, and the company admits that the auto dialer is theirs when asked about it. Am I expected to come up with a forensic procedure that covers all scenarios?

Comment: @HatterisMad So your plan for proving that your claims are true is hoping that the company you're complaining about tells SO that your claims are true, and that's it?

Comment: I understand your concern with proving the claim is legitimate. I however do not have the resources that you are asking for to convince you. I would have to trust that SO would be competent enough to field the claim on their own with whatever evidence I have to provide to them.

Comment: @HatterisMad What resources do you think SO has to find evidence that you don't have?  SO isn't the police.  If you came to the company that I work for and asserted that one of our clients was spamming people with phone calls I wouldn't be able to validate those claims, and I can't think of any resources SO has that I don't have access to.

Comment: I never implied that I expect SO to be hunting for evidence. I said that I would provide what evidence I had and they could review it and determine what to do with it, thus "fielding the claim" as I stated before.

Comment: @HatterisMad So now that we've established that you're not able to provide convincing evidence that your claims are true, and you're not expecting SO to find their own evidence that you don't have, what are you expecting SO to do in response to your claims, "fielding" them as you say, given that they can't determine the accuracy of those claims?  What would you *want* SO to do in response to unverified and unverifiable claims made by a single user?

Comment: What gives you the impression that I am not able to provide evidence? You seem to be attempting to derail the discussion topic by the logic that since a review process can't be perfect that there is no incentive to look into it in the first place.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not sure there's much we can do.  If Stack Overflow already replied that they can't take action on it...there's not much to say or to be done.  If the company continues to spam call you, you may be able to file a complaint with your phone company and see if there is some action that may be taken from that angle instead.

Comment: @HatterisMad Well I asked you how you'd be able to provide verifiable evidence for SO, and your response was that you expect the company to admit to your claims and to say that you can't be expected to provide evidence yourself.  If you *can* actually provide verifiable evidence, why have you not mentioned it thus far, specifically when I asked how you'd go about verifying to SO that your claims are true?  I didn't say it had to be perfect, I asked how how you could demonstrate your claims to be true, and your response was that you shouldn't have to (implying that you couldn't).

Comment: @Makoto SO did not reply saying that they can't take action on it. You are getting that from another comment of Servy that was inaccurate and deleted. This entire discussion topic is supposed to be whether SO should attempt to do something in a situation like this.

Comment: So you mean this phrase - **Instead the response that I received from SO was that since the abusive interactions that I have had with the company are not directed through SO, the only thing they offered to do was to direct my email to the company that is spamming me.** - is somehow meant to mean that Stack Overflow *can* take action on it??  I'm grateful to Servy for highlighting this point to me again, as it really boils down to:  not much we can do, you're going to need to get someone at another level to take action here, especially because they're not using our platform.

Comment: @Makoto The company is using the SO platform, and while SO can't stop the company from using their auto dialer with me, they can note this behavior and determine whether they want to expose SO users to a company that is known to use these practices

Comment: @Servy You seem to want evidence that is not open to interpretation. I told you i don't have the resources to do this. If i provide a phone record with a phone number that is linked to the company, it seems as though you are going to claim that the phone record is unauthentic. I don't have the resources to prove it to you and quite frankly it seems as though you are just trolling instead of trying to help this discussion.

Comment: The key is that they didn't use the SO platform to *specifically* target you.  You had no interactions with them beforehand.  You had no contact with them prior.  I stated this much before; the fact that they use SO and the fact that they're robocalling you are mutually exclusive.  Sorry that you're unsatisfied with this result, but in reality...there's not much else to say on it.  We meta-hounds aren't going to be of much value to you here.

Comment: @HatterisMad So you feel that if I told SO that Hatter is Mad was spamming my phone number with an auto-dialer, and I gave them my phone records (which has a fair amount of spam calls in there), you would expect them to take action against your SO account?  After all, that's the *exact same* evidence that you're providing, and expecting them to take action against another account with.  That you think *I'm* trolling *you* because I'm saying that providing claims with basically no evidence isn't something that SO can act on...

Comment: If the instance was similar to the current discussion question: I was an employer that was spamming you and was advertising on stack overflow careers. And I was spamming you with a phone number that can be traced back to me, and you can provide phone records that are authentic that shows that I have been spamming you. Then yes I think something should be done to my ability to advertise on Stack Overflow. Now could you please stop trying to make illogical hypotheticals to discredit me?

Comment: If you're in the United States, repeated unsolicited phone calls is a punishable action through the Federal Trade Commission and you can [report the phone number directly to them](https://www.ftccomplaintassistant.gov/) so that it can be investigated. If the company itself is involved, they'll likely receive large fines.

Comment: Experiencing this would make me furious. However, I wonder why you think it's "malicious". If they're calling you trying to get you to apply for a job, any sane person would realize that repeatedly calling like this isn't the way to do make someone want to work for them. I find it more likely that this is that special variety of incompetence so supremely advanced as to be indistinguishable from malice.

Comment: *Every time that I have talked to a human from this company* - just of curiosity - that was by calling the company *directly* via a listed number *you found* (off their website for instance) and asking for the HR department etc... and ask them what the heck they think they're doing and would they stop it? This could well be terrible recruitment practices but to me sounds like some weird phishing attempt/scam using a known name as pretense (I'll guess 45 positions means they could well be a household one) - for what purpose though *shrugs*.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Maybe malicious isn't the best word to use? It is entirely subjective as to whether the practices are morally acceptable. I suppose it feels more malicious as they continue to wake me up every morning after i have asked them at least twice to not ever contact me again.

Comment: @JonClements This should have been my first course of action but regrettably not how I handled the situation. I saw that the number is listed as being from the same town as them and when they answered the phone had a spiel of what jobs they had to offer me. It is entirely possible that someone is impersonating them and is using a spoofed phone number from that small town.

Comment: Hmm... can you use your profile to name-and-shame? Regardless of where they got your contact info, any company that behaves this way is not a company I want to business with or work for.

Comment: @shoover naming and shaming is dubious at the best of times and certainly not when it's not conclusively proven - let's not go there.

Comment: @Hatterismad anyway... For your own peace of mind - I'd look up their number and call them direct (maybe at State/HQ level?) If it's them then keep escalating till you get someone at Director level confirming they're going to stop and ask for it in writing. If they've really got no idea what you're going on about - then give them the details you have - they may appreciate being aware of what's going on and actually pursue it and protect their name by certain means before enough people get roped into any form of scam.

Comment: @JonClements Agreed, I will contact them at their publicly listed number tomorrow and see what response comes out of that.

Comment: Ah. Just seen at the bottom of Des' answer an account manager is going to reach out as well so might well be redundant but I'd probably still do it myself anyway. Good luck.

Comment: @HatterisMad Sorry to hear that, but is there any reason You cannot just block the number. Spam is always spam. Doesn't matter if they are selling pots or offering a job.

Comment: @JonClements I called them back at the auto dialer number today and pretended to be interested in their spiel. Got the names of the people I talked to and tried to reach them through the main phone number listed on the company website. Unfortunately I can't get anyone to answer the main company phone number. The spiel they were talking to me about was the job positions that they have listed on SO. I will keep trying to contact them through that main number and see if anyone ever answers.

Comment: Heaven forbid this happen to @Servy.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Thank you for raising this issue and I’m sorry you’re experiencing this. I reached out to our support team to confirm a few things (as you mentioned):

- The company did not get your contact information through Stack Overflow
- The company did not contact you through Stack Overflow
- The company is not abusing other users through our platform

Situations like this are tricky when the actions take place off-site. However, this sort of recruiting practice is not something we condone and while we can’t investigate your call logs, we do believe you. Even though they aren’t breaking any explicit terms on our site, we do feel a responsibility to contact any customer who would be violating our terms if they engaged in the same behavior through our site. We’ve asked the account manager for this customer to reach out directly.

Ultimately, companies that behave this way are just hurting themselves; we try to encourage constructive behavior through the rules we impose and the guidance we give them when they use Jobs, but when all is said and done if they’re determined to shoot themselves in the foot, they’re gonna do it.

Comment: Thank you @Des for looking into this for me. Truly I just don't want anyone else to go through what I had to go through. As JonClements pointed out in an earlier comment however, the phone number that I have been contacted from may not be a legitimate phone number for this company. Although the phone number is from the same area code and zone, it is not the identical phone number that they have listed on SO, and it is always possible that someone had spoofed the number and is impersonating them. I find that almost easier to believe than a company thinks that these practices are acceptable.

Comment: @HatterisMad I'm not sure if it's a possibility for where you are but in the UK we have the telephone preference services which if you're registered with it means *"It is a legal requirement that all organisations (including charities, voluntary organisations and political parties) do not make such calls to numbers registered on the TPS unless they have your consent to do so."*, there may be a similar service in your area

Comment: Perhaps the key thing here that was not evident to me from the question is "*The company did not get [the OP's] contact information through Stack Overflow*."  If that's true then SO is going above and beyond to attempt to influence the advertizer -- their own paying customer -- on behalf of a member in a situation to which SO is not a party in any way.  Bravo.

Comment: If in the UK, as @NickA suggested, there is a legal route you can take. The magic URL is: https://ico.org.uk/concerns/nuisance-calls-and-messages/spam-texts-and-nuisance-calls/report-spam-texts-and-nuisance-sales-calls/ - The ICO has the ability to validate such complaints and the power to fine companies which behave like this. As somebody who used to work in telephony, I can confirm that every complaint causes a panic *somewhere* (we often had to track down why a particular call was made and give them the details of the source company)

Comment: Looks like there's something similar in the US too: https://www.fcc.gov/consumers/guides/stop-unwanted-calls-and-texts (it has steps you can take, and see "File Your Complaint" at the bottom if those steps still don't work)

Comment: @NickA Although in regard to Spam callers generally in the UK the ICO is powerless to help when the caller is outside of the UK.  Of course if the Spammer illegally fakes the "Presentation number" which is what the Caller Display system reports to the callee that can also make it difficult to track the blighter down. 8-( {Although a clearly ludicrous number does help to screen them!}

Comment: @SlySven perhaps but I mentioned the TPS, *not* the ICO and even international calls have to go through TPS screening before calls are made (while they can't do much to stop it the screening helps) and even if the call is international you can report it to the ICO, see the [TPS FAQ](http://www.tpsonline.org.uk/tps/contactfaq.php)

Comment: @NickA Ah, and http://www.tpsonline.org.uk/tps/stillgetcalls.html does give a little more information about the limits on what the TPS can deal with.

Comment: @Dave Having made numerous complaints to the ICO about unwanted calls where a valid number is presented the calls continue to be made. Often they are robodialled and hence illegal in the first place. Many other spam calls are mde with number withheld and these cannot be complained about. Note, my number has been registered on the TPS for at least 3 years. If you call back the ones where you have a number and complain they just off to take you off their list. Fine until another spammer selling the same product calls you ...

Comment: @dave even the ICO is relatively toothless having only made 97 enforcement actions in the last 12 months. https://ico.org.uk/action-weve-taken/enforcement/. Given the huge number of such calls made every day that is a small drop in the ocean.

Comment: @Des have you had any success in contacting them? I have not been able to get through to a person through their main contact phone number on their website.